# Would Moses have taken the land of Sihon if he had not resisted in Deutoronomy 2:26-30?

Tags: deuteronomy, moses

God actually tells Moses to attack Sihon and take his land

Deutoronomy 2:24 NKJV

> 24 “ ‘Rise, take your journey, and cross over the River Arnon. Look, I have given into your hand  Sihon the Amorite, king of Heshbon, and his land. Begin to possess it, and engage him in battle.

But Moses actually negotiates with Sihon before taking his land

Deutoronomy 2:26 NKJV

> 26 “And I sent messengers from the Wilderness of Kedemoth to Sihon king of Heshbon, with  words of peace, saying,  27 ‘Let me pass through your land; I will keep strictly to the road, and I will turn neither to the right  nor to the left.  28 You shall sell me food for money, that I may eat, and give me water for money, that I may  drink; only let me pass through on foot,  29 just as the descendants of Esau who dwell in Seir and the Moabites who dwell in Ar did for  me, until I cross the Jordan to the land which the LORD our God is giving us.’  30 “But Sihon king of Heshbon would not let us pass through, for the LORD your God hardened  his spirit and made his heart obstinate, that He might deliver him into your hand, as it is this day.

It is only after Sihon's refusal for a passage through that Moses attacked him and took his land

Would Moses have attacked Sihon if he had actually agreed to give him passage?

Answer (score 1):

**The Reluctant Warriors**

In Deuteronomy Chapter 1 Moses recounts how the people of Israel were reluctant to go into Canaan as commanded, and how they then changed their minds, refusing God's command to refrain from going in, and finally their consequent routing by the Amorites.

Moses' recollection of Israel's journey continues in Deuteronomy 2, where he relates God's instructions to not meddle with Edom. In verse 8 (KJV), Moses recalls:

> And when **we passed by** from our brethren the children of Esau, which dwelt in Seir, through the way of the plain from Elath, and from Ezion -gaber, **we turned and passed by the way of the wilderness of Moab**.

So, Israel "*passed by*" Edom, going "*by the way of the wilderness of Moab*". Why? The reason for this is given in Numbers 20:14,17-21 (KJV):

> <sup>14</sup>And Moses sent messengers from Kadesh unto the king of Edom, Thus saith thy brother Israel, Thou knowest all the travail that hath befallen us: ...
>   <sup>17</sup>**Let us pass, I pray thee, through thy country: we will not pass through the fields, or through the vineyards, neither will we drink of the water of the wells: we will go by the king's high way, we will not turn to the right hand nor to the left, until we have passed thy borders.**
>   <sup>18</sup>And Edom said unto him, Thou shalt not pass by me, lest I come out against thee with the sword.
>   <sup>19</sup>And the children of Israel said unto him, We will go by the high way: and if I and my cattle drink of thy water, then I will pay for it: I will only, without doing any thing else, go through on my feet.

And Edom's reply:

> <sup>20</sup>... Thou shalt not go through.
>   **And Edom came out against him with much people, and with a strong hand.** 
>   <sup>21</sup>Thus Edom refused to give Israel passage through his border: **wherefore Israel turned away from him**.

The OP picks up the narrative of Deuteronomy 2 with the children of Israel at Heshbon, asking Sihon for permission to pass though his land. The words here are identical to those sent to the king of Edom.

Moses then notes:

> But Sihon king of Heshbon would not let us pass by him: for the LORD thy God hardened his spirit, and made his heart obstinate, that he might deliver him into thy hand, as appeareth this day.
>   -- Deuteronomy 2:30 (KJV)

This passage is of huge importance in regard shedding light on what it means when God says he hardens hearts/spirits. How did God harden Sihon's spirit? Did he make him behave in a way that he was not naturally inclined? I'm sure there are those who would like to read it that way, but, no, a little reflection on what had just transpired in the narrative yields a far more reasonable explanation.

God knew his people were reluctant warriors, for even though He tells them Sihon had been given into their hand, they were still compelled to pursue a pacifist approach. But all that was needed to harden Sihon's spirit and make his heart obstinate, was to ensure he got a report of what Edom had just done to Israel. There is no way Sihon's heart was naturally inclined to accommodate in his land more than half-a-million arrivals from the wilderness, so Edom's success in chasing Israel away emboldened Sihon to do the same, i.e. it hardened his resolve.

**Conclusion**

The people of Israel most certainly would not have mounted an attack on Sihon to obtain the supplies they needed. But God, being aware of Israel's reluctance in the matter of war, used the circumstances regarding Edom's having chased them away to harden Sihon's resolve (his heart) to do the same. However, Israel was now  compelled to engage Sihon who had come out in force to attack... and... wonder of wonders... they prevailed!! Their first victory on their march towards Canaan.